# Why alt+tab don't work when using xshell 4.0?

Tags: linux

I can't switch to other windows through the alt+tab when i'm using xshell.

could anyone give me a help? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue sounds like you have XShell set as "always on top"

First, make sure the Transparent option is disabled under the View option. Then, disable the following two options:

1. Make window opaque on mouse over
2. Always on top when transparent

Also, if the problem persists, please try resetting the registry key. To remove Xshell registry keys:

1. Click on the Windows Start menu and click Run.
2. Enter regedit and press enter.
3. Delete the following registry node:

\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NetSarang\Xshell

Comment: yes, i accidentally selected the 'always on top' under the view option. I disselect "always on top" and this problem was fixed. Thanks:)

Comment: if you are happy with this answer please select answer as accpeted.